# Get compact list of variables and dimension from NetCDF file in R

Tags: r, netcdf

I have a large number of NetCDF files in several directories, each containing a different set of variables and dimensions. I.,e, some files can have different dimensions than others.
Ultimately, I want to identify if files with identical names also contain identical data in terms of number of variables and dimensions.

I want to loop over the files and create a text file for each (with a similar name), that will hold a simple table of the variable names and dimensions.

The question is: how to get a table with the variable names and dimensions into a dataframe like:

| "id" | "name" | "type" | "lat" | "lon" | "height" | "Time" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "O3" | NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 1 | "NO2" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 18 | 1 | 768 |
| 2 | "NO" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 3 | "SO2" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |

EDIT:
I've used tidync library to create a DF and loop over them to add the dimensions, but it also lists the dimensions as variable, not only the variables.

```
library(tidync)
NCDims = tidync(paste0(NCDir, NCFile))  
Vars = as.data.frame(NCDims$variable)

Dims =as.data.frame(NCDims$dimension)
for (row in 1:nrow(Vars)) {
  VarName <- Vars[row, "name"]
  Vars[row,"lat"]    = Dims[which(Dims$name == "lat"),"length"] 
  Vars[row,"lon"]    = Dims[which(Dims$name == "lat"),"length"] 
  Vars[row,"height"] = Dims[which(Dims$name == "height"),"length"] 
  Vars[row,"Time"]   = Dims[which(Dims$name == "time"),"length"] 
}
```

Result:

| "id" | "name" | "type" | "lat" | "lon" | "height" | "Time" |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | "O3" | NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 1 | "NO2" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 18 | 1 | 768 |
| 2 | "NO" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 3 | "SO2" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 4 | "Time" | "NC_DOUBLE" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 5 | "lat" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 6 | "lon" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 7 | "HGT" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |
| 8 | "ZH" | "NC_FLOAT" | 185 | 185 | 1 | 768 |

Any ideas?
Thanks

Comment: You seem to be asking multiple questions. Which steps have you tried to do?

Answer (score 0):

For the record, here is the solution I came up with. It can probably be improved, but it is a start for anyone looking for a quick look at the content of multiple NetCDF files.

```
library(tidync)
library(ncdf4)

setwd(NC_Dir)   # set root directory 

ListFiles = list.files(pattern = "*.nc$")
NC_Files = data.frame()
Dir_txt  = gsub("\\\\", "_", NC_Dir)
Dir_txt  = gsub(":", "", Dir_txt)

iFile = 1

for (NCFile in ListFiles){
    FullName_CF = paste0(NC_Dir, NCFile)
    NC_CF_NCDF4 <- nc_open( FullName_CF) 
    FileStartTime = NC_CF_NCDF4$dim$Time$units
    nc_close(NC_CF_NCDF4)

    NCDims = tidync(FullName_CF)  
    Vars   = as.data.frame(NCDims$variable)    
    Dims   = as.data.frame(NCDims$dimension)

    NC_Files[iFile,"FileName"  ] = NCFile
    NC_Files[iFile,"Size"      ] = format(round(file.size(NCFile)/1024/1024,digits = 0),big.mark=",",scientific=FALSE)
    NC_Files[iFile,"lat"       ] = Dims[which(Dims$name == "lat"   ),"length"]
    NC_Files[iFile,"lon"       ] = Dims[which(Dims$name == "lon"   ),"length"]
    NC_Files[iFile,"height"    ] = Dims[which(Dims$name == "height"),"length"]
    NC_Files[iFile,"Time"      ] = Dims[which(Dims$name == "time"  ),"length"]
    NC_Files[iFile,"NVariables"] = length(Vars$name)
    NC_Files[iFile,"Variables" ] = paste(Vars$name,collapse=" ")
    
    iFile = iFile+1
}

write.csv(NC_Files, file = paste0("List_NC_",Dir_txt,format(Sys.time(), '%Y_%m_%d'),".csv"))
```